# Azure classic release pipeline stage won't trigger on "After stage" trigger if it was already successful from a previous run

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

There are 3 stages set up in a linear fashion using "After stage" triggers. Screenshot below:

[image]

On the initial trigger, when none of the stages have been triggered before, everything works fine and the stages are triggered sequentially. On the second run, however only the first stage runs which is triggered manually. The subsequent stages are not queued. The same can be observed in the above screenshot where the second and third stages where run at 2:55 am (the first run) and the first stage was run at 2:57 am (depicting the second run).

Comment: Does the answer below resolved your question? If yes, you could accept it as answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you deploy or redeploy a single stage on the release summary page, the other stages will not be triggered.

When should I manually deploy stages on the release summary page:

- After you create a release, you can use it to redeploy the artifacts
  to any of the stages defined in that release. This is useful if you
  want to perform regular manual releases, or set up a continuous
  integration stage trigger that redeploys the artifacts using this
  release. Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops#when-and-why-would-i-abandon-a-release).
- When a deployment of a release fails for a stage, you can redeploy
  the same release to that stage. Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/releases?view=azure-devops).

If you want to deploy all stages again, you should create a new release.[image]